# Using JSX in IO.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsx

I am work a React.js app with express using IO.js. And i make a HelloWorld class with a JSX component, that it will be return.

```
'use strict'
 const React=require('react');
 class HelloWorld extends React.component{
  render(){
   return <h1>Hello,{this.props.name}</h1>
  }
 }
 module.exports=HelloWorld
```

When i compile this on IO.js make this error:

```
return <h1>Hello,{this.props.name}</h1>
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
 at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
 at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
 at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
 at require (module.js:384:17)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/raulgf92/Proyectos/helloWorldReact/index.js:4:18)
 at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
```

The evident problem was the compile JSX. IO.js ¿Has IO.js any compile flag, to use JSX on this program? Or I need use a previusly babel compilate?

Comment: No, you need to use babel.

Comment: I know, i solve use babel. But could be a IO.js flag so translate JSX

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using io.js instead of Node.js? The last release of io.js was in September 2015, and there won't be anymore updates, as the io.js project has merged back into Node.js.

Comment: I don't know nothing about this. I use IO and not node.js only for the use without flags and compatibility with ES6. I hate using babel to translate all my projects to ES5 from ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using babel can solve the problem, but a IO.js fflag for JSX, would be more effective solution. For translare JSX in babel:

1. Install babel:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env
   npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
   ```
2. Load .babelrc:

   ```
   {
    "plugins": [
     ["transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "dom" // default pragma is React.createElement
     }]
    ]
   }
   ```
3. Translate the code or the class you like using the comand:

   ```
   babel --plugins transform-react-jsx FILE_TO_TRANSFORM >> FILE_TO_SAVE
   ```